# nerdctl run `no such file or directory` when running inside a pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd, nerdctl

I have a Pod

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ...
  name: ...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ...
      image: ...
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
        runAsUser: 0
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/containerd
          name: containerd-dir
        - mountPath: /var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
          name: containerd
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
    - name: containerd
      hostPath:
        path: /var/run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock
    - name: containerd-dir
      hostPath:
        path: /var/run/containerd
```

which mounts the `containerd.sock`. Inside the pod, I have `nerdctl` installed (`RUN /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew install nerdctl`)

I'm able to run `nerdctl ps` successfully, and it returns a list of the running contains (that I ran from the host) - but when I try to run `nerdctl run`, for example `nerdctl run -d redis`, I get the error message

```
FATA[0000] no such file or directory
```

Running `nerdctl --debug-full run -d redis` doesn't reveal anything

```
/# nerdctl --debug-full run redis
DEBU[0000] verification process skipped                 
FATA[0000] no such file or directory
```

`nerdctl run` works fine when I run it on the host (targets the same `containerd.sock`) and inside the pod when I run `nerdctl ps`, I see the containers that I launched succeessfully on the host.

`nerdctl pull` works fine from within the pod

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to directly interact with the container runtime?  Can you use the Kubernetes API instead?

Comment: Please check the mentioned link which will be useful https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/issues/1145